# Vector dev how to use hypenated key names?

Tags: vector-vrl

Sometimes, when processing log events in vector, a log source might have hyphens as key names - for example json structured logs. Assuming it is from a third party and changing them there is not an option, how can we handle these keys?

A sample log message (contrived for demonstration) is:

```
{
  "labels":{"no_hypens":"normal field","this-has-hypens":"this is a test"},
  "message":"a message",
  "timestamp":"2022-11-01T12:03:00.941866394Z"
}
```

Note the field `labels.this-has-hyphens` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to put together a test case, and find out the syntax, both in providing test data like this and in extracting the data in VRL:

The test case

```
---
tests:
  - name: hypens
    inputs:
      - insert_at: hypens
        type: log
        log_fields:
          labels."this-has-hypens": "this is a test"
          labels.no_hypens: "normal field"
    outputs:
      - extract_from: hypens
        conditions:
          - type: vrl
            source: |
              assert_eq!("normal field", .no_hypens)
              assert_eq!("this is a test", .output_without_hypens)
```

This will insert and check for two fields from the input data. Note the hyphenated key segment needs to be quoted.

Next the VRL in the transform:

```
---
transforms:
  hypens:
    type: remap
    inputs:
      - route
    source: |
      log(., "error")

      . = {
        "no_hypens": .labels.no_hypens,
        "output_without_hypens": .labels."this-has-hypens",
      }
```

The log message is there as while debugging this, I had to figure out that the test hyphenated field didn't even get to the transform until I had quotes around it.
Then the field reference itself needs to have quotes too, after the dot (not square brackets).

This will pass the tests, and output the right data.